# Trying to add an item to a list through console app

Tags: c#

I'm working on a project in C# that has 3 movie lists

- recommended
- seen movies
- Saved movies

Each movie has an id number

The task I need to do it from the console app

The recommended movies should be able to be saved in the seen movies list or saved movies list

Comment: It would be a good idea to post the relevant part of the code you're working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need an object representing the movie:

```
public class Movie
{
    public MOVIE_TYPE {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public int ID{get;set;}
}
```

In your main class you have to create a list containing the movie objects. The MOVIE_TYPES are indicating whether they are seen or not.